# In this multi-threaded client application why cant i download two files at once when creating two instances of the class?

Tags: python, multithreading

```
from tkinter import*
import socket, threading, struct, os, getpass

class clientDownload(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, message, file, length):
        self.file = file
        self.length = length
        self.finish = 0
        self.message = message
        self.sock = 0

        self.x = Listbox(download_frame,height = 1, borderwidth = 4, bg = 'light green', width = 60)
        self.x.grid(row =len(download_list), column = 0)
        self.x.insert(END, box_list[file]) 

        self.y = Label(download_frame, height = 1, width = 16, text = "Downloading: ", bg = 'gold')
        self.y.grid(row = len(download_list), column = 1)
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        addr = ('127.0.0.1', 5555)
        self.sock.connect(addr)

        msg = self.send_msg()
        self.sock.sendall(msg)

        received_message = self.recv_msg()
        if self.finish == 1:
            self.remove_two()
        else:
            f = open(box_list[self.file], 'wb')
            f.write(received_message)
            f.close()
            self.sock.close()
            self.remove_two()


    def send_msg(self):
        self.message = struct.pack('>I', len(self.message)) + self.message
        return self.message

    def recv_msg(self):
        raw_msglen = self.recvall(4, 0)
        if not raw_msglen:
            return None
        msglen = struct.unpack('>I', raw_msglen)[0]
        return self.recvall(msglen, 1)

    def recvall(self, n, a):
        data = self.sock.recv(1)
        while len(data) < n and self.finish == 0:
            packet = self.sock.recv(n - len(data))
            if not packet:
                return None
            data += packet
            if a == 1:
                progress = (len(data)/n)* 10000
                remainder = progress % 1
                progress -= remainder
                progress /= 100
                self.y.config(text = 'Downloading: ' + str(progress))
        return data
```

Comment: the error that im getting is memory error within the recvall() at data += packet. This only happens when i send two client requests. The code works fine for one request.

Comment: You should add that information to the question by editing it instead of just putting it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

For stating the obvious, `MemoryError` means you've run out of available memory for you process - which was bound to happen since you store all your download data in memory. It might have happened with a huge enough single download, and it could work with two or more small enough "concurrent" downloads (for values of "huge" and "small" depending on your hardware, os etc).

The very obvious fix is to write your data to a temporary file instead of storing them in memory.